# Send plaintext / html mixed e-mails using mutt

Tags: html, plaintext, mutt

I'd like to use mutt to send an mixed plaintext / html email.

Below won't work because the boundary id isn't set (of course).

```
mutt -s "mixed body test" me@mydomain.tld < plaintext_html_body.txt
```

Here a sample of a mixed e-mail which I sent from my Gmail account. This is more or less how the Source code of the e-mail should look like.

```
...
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=94eb2c088fb8697aed054afba7bf
...

--94eb2c088fb8697aed054afba7bf
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

This is a HTML Test
This is a HTML Test

--94eb2c088fb8697aed054afba7bf
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<div dir="ltr">
<span style="background-color:rgb(0,255,255)">
This is a HTML Test<br>
</span>
<span style="background-color:rgb(69,129,142)">
This is a HTML Test<br>
</span>
</div>

--94eb2c088fb8697aed054afba7bf--
```

Can mutt generate `Content-Type:` headers automatically (including boundary ids) or does it have any kind of mechanisms allowing to combine plaintext and html bodies?

If all breaks down, would manual generation of the entire body (including `Content-Type:` headers, boundary ids, both bodies) work?

Any alternative ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since mutt lets you edit email headers, you can manually insert a content-type line when composing a message.

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Subject: yadayada
```

You can probably go further and generate the boundaries and whatnot manually.
See also 'mpack' (ref: https://www.tecmint.com/send-email-attachment-from-linux-commandline/)